# Splice from array works only in one order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, string, checkbox

I have a little problem. 
I have a checkbox for showing div. I can choose from 6 different checkboxes to select which div I want to show.

When check checkboxes I show div and send to server checked name of div.

```
 $scope.savesGraphUserDetail = [];
    $scope.addRemoveUserChart = function(checked, value) {
      if (checked) {
        $scope.savesGraphUserDetail.push(value);

        var config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT" } };
        var data = {graphsConfig: $scope.savesGraphUserDetail};

        $http
        .post(serviceBase + "blabla", data, config)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          })
          .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
          });
      }else {
        var index = $scope.savesGraphUserDetail.indexOf(value);
        $scope.savesGraphUserDetail.splice(index);

        var config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT" } };
        var data = {graphsConfig: $scope.savesGraphUserDetail};

        $http
          .post(serviceBase + "blabla", data, config)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          })
          .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
          });
      }
```

And this is ok, 
but when I uncheck checkboxes I get a problem, because if I check in this order 
first click "A", second "C" and third "D" I push in my array like this

```
myArray = ["A", "C", "D"]
```

And if I uncheck in reverse order, 
first uncheck "D"

```
myArray = ["A", "C"]
```

second uncheck "C"

```
myArray = ["A"]
```

and last "A"

```
myArray = []
```

and this is perfect, but if I change order when unchecking checkboxes

```
myArray = ["A", "C", "D"]
```

if I first uncheck "C", my array remove "C" and "D", i get this

```
myArray = ["A"]
```

if I first uncheck "A", my array remove "A" and "C" and "D", I get this

```
myArray = []
```

How to remove an only unchecked item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `deleteCount` of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), because without all elements starting with the actual index are deleted.

> #### Parameters
>
> **`deleteCount`** <sub>Optional</sub>
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If `deleteCount` is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element. If `deleteCount` is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at `start`, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> If `deleteCount` is omitted, or if its value is larger than `array.length - start`, then all of the elements beginning with `start` index on through the end of the array will be deleted.

```
$scope.savesGraphUserDetail.splice(index, 1);
//                                        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling **[`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** with the `index` only, you need to sepecify `1` as second parameter, which is the number of items to be spliced, the `deleteCount` optional param.

```
var index = $scope.savesGraphUserDetail.indexOf(value);
$scope.savesGraphUserDetail.splice(index, 1);
```

Otherwise all of the elements beginning with start index on through the end of the array will be deleted, that's why `"C"` and `"D"` were deleted in your second try.

**Documentation:**

If you take a look at the **[`.splice()` MDN specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**, you can see that:

[image]